# .NET integration Framework

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Is there any kind of framework that provides some generic mechanism for integration between applications or something similar? By integration I presume data exchange (import and export) between two applications via some standard interface like Web Service.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is - [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

You can use that to communicate via Web Services over HTTP (SOAP or REST), TCP, Named Pipes, and many other protocols.

More traditional Inter-Process Communication (IPC) methods include [Named Pipes](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/remoting/article.php/c7259), [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx), [Memory-Mapped Files](http://github.com/tomasr/filemap), and [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011.aspx).  But I would really recommend WCF over any of those, it's a lot easier to get up and running.

Comment: +1 here - this is the entire purpose of WCF. Go check it out and learn it - it's insanely powerful!!

Answer (score 1):

WCF works great for highly coupled systems, however, if you need your systems to be loosely coupled, try a message based framework like [nServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may read about [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).